# Plugin Situation: What to do with dependent libraries?

Tags: c#, mef

I have a MEF-based application which uses adapters to process files. It uses configuration files to determine which directories to watch and which adapter to use to process each type of file. Plugins take the form of a .dll that implements a common interface.

Each .dll requires its own set of dependent libaries. For instance, plugin1.dll might need to use apilibrary.dll and xmllibrary.dll. It is also possible that at a later date I might want to add plugin2.dll, and plugin2.dll might use xmllibrary.dll as well. These dependent libraries are updated regularly, so I can't count on plugin2.dll using the exact same version of xmllibrary.dll used in plugin1.dll.

I'd like to compile each plugin to one .dll file that invisibly includes within itself all of its dependent libraries, which seems like one way to solve this problem. Alternately, I'd like to figure out how each .dll file can look for its dependent libaries in a subfolder, which I believe would also reduce the possibility of versioning conflicts. Or maybe there's a dead simple solution to this problem that I haven't even considered (which is always very, very likely).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably try to get this to work with standard .NET loading rules.  However, if you do need to control exactly how assemblies are loaded and which versions are loaded, this blog post shows how: [Using Loading contexts effectively](http://hammett.castleproject.org/index.php/2011/03/using-loading-contexts-effectively/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to weigh up deployability vs. maintenance.  The simple solution is to use a tool called **ILMerge**. ILMerge takes your project output and can take other assemblies and merge them together. This enables you to wrap up all of the assemblies that your plugin is dependent on, and merge them into a single assembly. Optionally you can do things like re-signing with your public key, etc. Here is a good read: [Leveraging ILMerge to simplify deployment and your users experience](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/leveraging-ilmerge-to-simplify-deployment-and-your-users-experience/) by [Daniel Cazzulino](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/).

But while that is good, what happens if a new version of the referenced assembly is distributed that corrects bugs in that which you have embedded? By the rules of Fusions assembly loader, when it loads the types from your referenced assembly, it will see that they have already been loaded, so there is no reason for it to load the updated version. This would then mean you need to recompile your plugin and merge the newer referenced assembly again.

My question would be, is it *really* that important to ensure a specific version is used? If a newer version provides an updated implementation (that doesn't break backwards compatibility) then surely this should benefit all plugins that need to reference it?

As for as how assemblies are loaded in reference to each other, have a read of [Understanding .Net Assemblies and References](http://www.codecreations.com/site/programming/57-understanding-net-assemblies-and-references?showall=1), which is an invaluable piece of information.

Comment: Perhaps I'm going on an invalid assumption: If I create a project and deploy it using v3 of some dependent library, and I later remove the v3 .dll and replace it with v4, won't that cause errors?

Comment: It depends if the referenced assembly is strongly named. A strongly named assembly will enforce the exact version usage unless overridden by binding redirects, policy files, etc. It the assembly is not strongly named, it doesn't guarantee that it is the same version lineage as the version that was present.  You would need to manage how you support this through your deployment model.

Answer (score 0):

MEF uses standard .NET assembly loading, and everything's loaded in a single AppDomain.  You have very little control over how dependencies are loaded - as they just get loaded automatically by the CLR when the assembly is injected via MEF.  Normal CLR assembly loading rules apply when using MEF, so dependencies will be loaded as if they were a dependency of your application - no matter where they're located or referenced.

For the most part, if the plugins and their dependencies are properly written, you most likely will not need to worry about this.  As long as the versioning in the dependencies is correct, it will likely just work.